# makefile rules precedence for similar file names

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile similar to the following:

```
dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz: release

myapp_%: $(SRC)
  recipe1

release:
  recipe2

sometarget: dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz
  recipe3
```

I'm running `make sometarget`, which requires `dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz`. I expect this requirement to be satisfied using recipe2 (release target) thanks to the specific target in the first line, but it is being built using recipe1. what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

(just for context the `myapp_%` target is meant to build a binary in the root directory called `myapp_darwin`, and the `dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz` is meant to build a different artifact, an archive for distribution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is make always wants a recipe for each target.  If you write this with no recipe associated with it:

```
dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz: release
```

that's not defining a rule for the target `dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz`, all that's doing is adding a new prerequisite `release` to that target.  Make will still have to search its rules database to find a rule to build that target with, and it will match the pattern rule.

So, it will run *both* `recipe2` then `recipe1`.

If you want to declare an explicit rule for the target then you have to give it a recipe, even if it's a no-op:

```
dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz: release
         @:
```

Now make has a recipe for this target and it won't need to go looking for one via implicit rule search.

Comment: You could as well define it as an empty rule, i.e. >>dist/myapp_darwin.tar.gz: release ;<< (note the comma). See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Recipes for reference.